# Arc/Semicircle Shape in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm looking to draw an arc type shape in Jetpack Compose but I'm really struggling to figure out the best way to do it. When I use drawArc, I can't seem to start the arc from the bottom left corner, it just starts from left middle. I've also tried drawRoundRect but I can't find a way to just round the top left and top right corners.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw it like this

Placed it to center for demonstration and border is to show that it doesn't overflow Canvas, if you don't pay attention, Canvas draws out of its borders unless use `Modifier.clipbounds()` is used on Canvas Modifier.

Trick for drawing half arc is to set **two times of Canvas height**, since arc is drawn inside a rectangle in principle. Changind height of Modifier of canvas changes height of arc.

```
        Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Canvas(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(80.dp),
            ) {

                val canvasWidth = size.width
                val canvasHeight = size.height

                drawArc(
                    Color.Blue,
                    startAngle = 180f,
                    sweepAngle = 180f,
                    useCenter = true,
                    size = Size(canvasWidth, 2 * canvasHeight)
                )

                val handleWidth = 200f
                val handleHeight = 30f

                drawRoundRect(
                    Color.White,
                    size = Size(handleWidth, handleHeight),
                    cornerRadius = CornerRadius(5.dp.toPx(), 5.dp.toPx()),
                    topLeft = Offset((canvasWidth - handleWidth) / 2, (canvasHeight - handleHeight)/2)
                )

            }
        }
```

Result

[image]

You can check this [tutorial about Jetpack Compose](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials#graphics) which covers Canvas operations in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it by using a a canvas with your device width but try to increase arc limits beyond device width. With this code

```
            Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                val canvasWidth = size.width
                val canvasHeight = size.height
                val formWidth = (canvasWidth * 2)
                val xPos = canvasWidth / 2

                drawArc(
                    Color.Black,
                    0f,
                    -180f,
                    useCenter = true,
                    size = Size(formWidth, 600f),
                    topLeft = Offset(x = -xPos, y = canvasHeight - 300)
                )
            }
```

Arc at bottom looks like this:

[image]

[more info](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/foundation/canvas/)